# Screen events in Caliburn Micro (showing message box at startup)

Tags: xaml, caliburn.micro

I want to show message box on app start.
I used `OnActivated` method of my first screen to show modal dialog.

It worked fine. And the case when user deactivated app without pressing Ok worked fine. After activating app again new `messageBox` was shown. Perfect.

But issue was that app wasn't completely initialized and OS killed app after 5 or 10 sec of waiting.

I tried to use `OnViewLoaded` event. But this event doesn't fire every time screen is `navigatedTo`.

Can i somehow get some event fired every time form is navigated to but bit later (like `OnViewLoaded` event) ?

OR

At what point OS stops its timeout timer ? 
As i see at `OnNavigated` it is forbidden to show modal dialogs, but at `Loaded` handler - already possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for quick self-answer. Suddenly discovered a small hack.

I've ovverriden OnNavigatedTo method like that

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    base.InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

And i show MessageBox at Caliburns `OnViewReady` method.

As a result

1. app is not killed by OS for taking >10 sec of load time.
2. message box is re-shown after deactivate-dorment-activate cycle.